# Preferred JavaScript Idiom for class definition

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

What is the preferred idiom for defining a class in JavaScript? I could define a *constructor function* for complex numbers as follows:

```
function Complex(real, imag) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag || 0.0;
    this.add = function(other) {
        this.real += other.real;
        this.imag += other.imag;
        return this;
    }
}
```

or I could do the following:

```
function Complex(real, imag) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag || 0.0;
}

Complex.prototype = {
    add : function(other) {
        this.real += other.real;
        this.imag += other.imag;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Since neither textbook  *JavaScript : The Good Parts* nor *JavaScript The Definitive Guide* define classes the first way I suspect these are *not* equivalent -- I suspect I need use `prototype` if I plan on using inheritance. This seems a little murky to me --  can anyone clarify this?

I know I could use the `Object.create()` method suggested in the aforementioned texts and do things the prototypical way, but I don't see folks doing this in practice much.

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions.

Comment: I figured as much, but I couldn't find an *exact* answer. Maybe someone could just confirm my suspicions, and I can remove the question.

Comment: There are no real classes in javascript, just new instances of functions. When prototyping you create a new property that inherits, so when the "parent" is changed, so it the "child" etc.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that JS uses prototypical inheritance. The notion of a class still exists I.e. objects that have the same prototype are considered to be of the same class.

Comment: Maybe the following helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 using prototype produces code that can be better optimized, has recognizable inheritance patterns and will consume less memory when creating a lot of instances. If you reply to comments it's better to use @ or the person commented will not be notified

Comment: Thanks @HMR, so I guess the `this.add = function(other) {...}` is *not* adding the method to `Complex.prototype`, but every object gets its own copy of the function. Thanks, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, every new object get's its own copy of the `add()` method.

In the second example, every new object share's a single copy of the `add()` function via the `prototype`.

Obviously the latter is more efficient.